# I use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to sync with iCloud, in debug works but installing from TestFlight no

Tags: core-data, icloud, cloudkit, nspersistentcloudkitcontainer

I use **NSPersistentCloudKitContainer** to sync with user iCloud the data, it works perfectly installing through Xcode on device but when install from TestFlight it doesn't work at all seems there is Production environment but I don't know how to pass from test to production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you go to the [CloudKit dashboard](https://icloud.developer.apple.com/) > CloudKit Database and deploy the schema to production.